# SPF for amazon EC2 and route53

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, spf, dkim

I am attempting to setup my own email server on ec2. Also, I m using route53 for DNS. Also, I m using elastic IP to get static public IP. My question is where will i setup SPF, DKIM and DMARC records in route53 or in my bigrock control panel. My domain in hosted in ec2 instance. Any information about setting up these records will be of great help

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to Route 53, and to the hosted zone in question.  Create an MX record for the email server, e.g. pop.myserver.com.  Then just follow the doc at: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/welcome-dns-service.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#SPFFormat

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=229677

Comment: No problem.  Can you do me a favor and accept this as answered?  That will give us both some rep.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Click the up arrow to mark as a useful answer, then click underneath the down arrow to accept as 'the' answer that solved your problem.  You get 2 rep for doing that.